# Check Date and Display Until Event Date

Tags: php, javascript

I want to list an event in the sidebar and have it automatically disappear on the day after the event.

```
<h6>Next Meeting</h6>
<dl id="nextmeeting">
<dt><a href="members-meetings.html">Oct 15, 2011</a></dt>
<dd>La Quinta Inn & Suites</dd>
<dd>303 Blum, San Antonio</dd>
</dl>
```

So, on October 16th, I want that info to be hidden. I am sure there is a simple PHP or JavaScript solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to generate the sidebar?  Where is the data coming from a database some where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if(strtotime('2011-10-16') > time()): ?>
<h6>Next Meeting</h6>
<dl id="nextmeeting">
<dt><a href="members-meetings.html">Oct 15, 2011</a></dt>
<dd>La Quinta Inn & Suites</dd>
<dd>303 Blum, San Antonio</dd>
</dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```